# UITableView showing a mark in the middle of the screen after scrolling

Tags: ios, ios9

I am using iOS9 and recently have seen a weird output from UITableView.

I had used `_tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;`

But after running, while scrolling on device, I had observed that there is black mark int he middle of the screen which will be around a pixel height.

Following are screenshots, 1 is before scrolling, 2 is after scrolling till end of screen

[image]
[image]

Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
switch (indexPath.row)
 {
 case 1:
 cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:secondCell];
 break;
 case 2:
 cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TitleCell];
 break;
 case 3:
 cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PartnerCell];
 break;
 case 4:
 cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SaveCell];
 break;
 default:
 cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AnimationCells];
 break;
 }    
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code.

Comment: You have a debugger. Debug! Use the view debugger to understand what the mark is.

Comment: @matt, I tried inspecting through viewDebugger, still could not reach to a solution. The view inspector was showing the cell separators where I had made `_tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;` and on device there are no cell separators visible as you can see in the above screenshots.